# Prism DelegateCommand not firing on SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I have the following delegate command:

ViewModel

using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Photography.ViewModels
{
public class ApertureDataGridViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

```
    private readonly ConnectedRepository _repo = new ConnectedRepository();

    public DelegateCommand<object> SelectionChangedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Aperture> Apertures { get; set; }

    public ApertureDataGridViewModel()
    {
        SelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SelectionChanged);

        Apertures = new ObservableCollection<Aperture>(_repo.GetApertures());
    }
   
    public void SelectionChanged(object param)
    {
        if (param == null)
        return;
     }
```

View

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Photography.Views.ApertureDataGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:Photography.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <vw:TableEditWindow x:Key="TableEditWindow"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridEdit"
                  AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ApertureName}"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Apertures}"                  
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  Style="{DynamicResource SelectorDataGrid}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DatagridRowSelected}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,
                                               ElementName=DataGridEdit}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MainForegroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MainForegroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ApertureId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ApertureName}" Header="Name" Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Active}" Header="Active" Width="3*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Notes}" Header="Notes" Width="10*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="5 5 5 5 ">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height=" auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Name: " Style="{DynamicResource LabelExpandedRow}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ApertureName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Active: " Style="{DynamicResource LabelExpandedRow}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Active}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Notes: " Style="{DynamicResource LabelExpandedRow}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Notes}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxExpandedRow}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Calling Window View

```
 <!--row 2-->
        <ContentControl
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="10 10 10 10"
                Visibility="{Binding ViewVisible, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ControlViewVisibleConverter},
                    ConverterParameter=Aperture}">
                <vw:ApertureDataGridView Visibility="Visible"/>
        </ContentControl>
```

I've used the exact same code in different parts of the application. Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply bind the `SelectedItem` to some property and execute code in the setter?

Comment: Also `DelegateCommand` looks weird, try [`RelayCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) implementation.

Comment: @aepot `DelegateCommand` is the name of prism's `RelayCommand` implementation

Comment: @Haukinger ah, ok, let it be. Thanks.

Comment: aepot. I decided to take your recommendation. Thanks. But if anyone can answer my original question, please let me know. I've used DelegateCommands in the past with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredibly, the debug stop wasn't working. As soon as I moved it to a new location I discovered the DelegateCommand was working. Never experienced this before.
Thanks everyone who responded.